# Correct way of calling a component/function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

There are many ways to call a function in React. Can you explain when I should use `<Function />` and when to use `{Function()}`? It seems like both do the same job.

Here is my sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    {App()}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

and inside the App.js I have:

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My favourite list</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>List  1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Output of the following program:
[image: Program output]

Comment: Technically both are right, the only difference is, one is JavaScript based and another is JSX based. But the correct way is `<Component />` - JSX way.

Comment: `<App />` - this is the React way. Instead of calling the `App` function yourself, let React do it for you.

Comment: @nthnchu - React is just a library, not an extension to JavaScript. (JSX, on the other hand, is an extension to JavaScript used [usually] with React and a few other libraries).

Comment: IMHO this is a *really good* beginner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Is it a component? Then use `<App />` (or `React.createElement`).

---

The difference is subtle. Fundamentally, if the function is a *component* (like your `App` function), use it as a component: `<App />` (or via [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)).

If the function is just a function that *returns* some elements, you can call it either way, but I would give it a name with a lower-case initial letter and call it directly. That said, it's **very** rare to want to write a function that returns some React elements rather than a pure functional component.

The difference relates to state and related concepts: A functional component can have state and such (via [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)), but a function you just call can't.

Here's an example trying to use hooks in the function, successfully via `<Example />`:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setCount(c => {
                if (c >= 10) {
                    clearInterval(handle);
                } else {
                    ++c;
                }
                return c;
            });
        }, 500);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
     
    return <div>{count}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div><Example /></div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

...and unsuccessfully via `{Example()}`:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setCount(c => {
                if (c >= 10) {
                    clearInterval(handle);
                } else {
                    ++c;
                }
                return c;
            });
        }, 500);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
     
    return <div>{count}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>{Example()}</div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
Look in the real browser console for a detailed error message (this snippet uses the development libraries to get detailed messages).
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically both are right, the only difference is, one is JavaScript based and another is JSX based. But the correct way is `<Component />` - JSX way.

Another difference is the children. If you want to send `props`, you may as well go away with sending an object. What about complex children and nested children? Will you be creating them?

Technically, the JSX that you write gets transpiled into what you have showed - method 2.

In reality, if you have something like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Hello</p>;
  }
}
```

The above gets transpiled into:

```js
"use strict";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", null, "Hello");
  }
}
```

**In a nutshell:** One is a JSX way and the other is JavaScript way. Most of the developers prefer JSX instead of JavaScript for readability and maintainability.

Comment: I think the bigger issue is that `App()` doesn't create a React element; `<App />` (or `React.creatElement(app)`) does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. But the above is a transpiler output. How does it do the `createElement` part then?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The output that I showed is a Babel Transpiler output. The function above gets `React.creatElement(app)` automatically triggered. Why did you say that it doesn't create a React Element? I am not sure why you mentioned that first comment? I mean, why do you think?

Comment: The `createElement` call in the transpiled code you've shown is to create the `p`, not the `App`. The difference between `<App />` and `App()` is that the former tranpiles to `React.createElement(App, null)` but the latter is unchanged (`App()`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yea, thanks for the clarification. 

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J && Praveen 